# Manipulating DOM inside custom function constructor

Tags: javascript, svg, function-constructor

I wrote a function constructor with a prototype that is creating svg picture and inserting it into the web page. I have 2 questions though:

1 Is it all right to take part of the code inside of constructor that is being used in the process of creating instance and move it to the prototype object. As far as I see these prototype methods are used generally with already created instances, for example `var a = [2,3,4]; a.reverse()`

2 Is it fine to manipulate DOM-objects that way inside of function constructor? DOM objects are not js native objects, they are host objects outside of js-engine.They are similar to js objects but created by browser somewhere else

Below is the code:

```js
function Sektor(selector, options) {
// Find a DOM object representing the HTML element with the supplied selector
// create a property called element
// This DOM object is assigned to the element property
  this.element = document.querySelector(selector);

// Some default values in case nothing is supplied
  const defaultOptions = {
    size: 100,
    circleColor: '#b3c9e0'
  };

// Merge options with default ones
  options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);
 
// Circle dimensions
  options.center = options.size / 2;
  options.radius = options.center;
  
// create a property called options
  this.options = options;

// Get SVG
  const svg = this.getCircle();

// SVG is injected into the DOM element with JavaScript
  this.element.innerHTML = svg;
}

// Assigning a method to the constructor's prototype
// This method generates SVG
Sektor.prototype.getCircle = function() {
  const options = this.options;
  return `
  <svg class='Sektor' viewBox='0 0 ${options.size} ${options.size}'> 
  <circle class='Sektor-circle' fill=${options.circleColor} cx='${options.center}' cy='${options.center}' r='${options.radius}' />
  </svg>
  `;
};


var sektor = new Sektor( '.example-one', { circleColor: '#7da385' } );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
 <title>Draw</title>
 <style>
body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.examples {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 padding: 20px;
}

.example {
 margin: 0px auto;
}

.Sektor {
 width: 200px;
 height: 200px;
 background-color:#f2f2f2;
}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class='examples'>
  <div class='example'>
   <div class='example-one'></div>
  </div>
 </div>  
 <script src='sektor.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: You have the order in the default options wrong (`options = Object.assign(defaultOptions, options);`). `Object.assign()` modifies the first given object, so you modify the default options but it should be the other way round

Comment: I understand that you recommend to take user options and override them with default options. It is not ok

Comment: I would use [document.createDocumentFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment). First I would use `document.createElementNS`to create the SVG element and the shapes inside. Next I would append the SVG to the fragment and the fragment to the DOM.

Comment: Very interesting. I need to try this

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel The order is fine, it's just a bit odd in the naming. The `defaultOptions` are a new object, not shared amongst the instances.

Comment: Will you add further methods in the future, and would use invoke them on the `sektor` instance?

Comment: @Bergi oh I see, but then it could be beneficial to move the defaultoptions out of the scope

Comment: @Bergi I will probably add similar methods to the prototype object, to add something. And I am not going to invoke any methods on instances. Just want to know if it is good practice to move statements partially to prototype object

Comment: @sgko If you don't want to deal with any instances, there's no point in creating objects. You should not use `class` at all. Use plain `function`s, and yes it's a good practice to factor out statements into small helper functions.

Comment: plain function will make things simpler.thanks